# Galaxy tab 2 10.1 (GT-P5113) stuck on samsung starting screen after update

Tags: boot

got update screen & clicked on it to update. When it was done it rebooted but is stuck on start up screen that says Samsung

Answer (score 0):

Force shut down the tablet then boot in recovery and delete cache, reboot. should pass now.